# how to scale 2D point cloud in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst, point-clouds

I am doing a 3D face identification & verification project using matlab. Now I am trouble in scaling 2D points into 3D cloud. Can anyone help me? Here is the code..I have scaled 2D point cloud manually for better view. myOne.mat is 3D image's xyz coordinates & 2Dfinal.mat is 2D image's xy coordinates.

```
clear; close all; clc;
 load('myOne.mat');
load('2Dfinal.mat');

% 2D point rotate
    [imrow, imclm, ~] = size(image);
    B(:,1) = imclm - f1match(:,1);
    B(:,2) = imclm - f1match(:,2);

% 2D point plot with specific point

subplot(1,2,1)
B = 300*B;
plot(B(:,1),B(:,2),'r.');

%2D points with 3D cloud

subplot(1,2,2)
showPointCloud(myOne(:,1:3));
hold on
plot(B(:,1),B(:,2),'r.');
hold off
```

[image: output]

Comment: I don't really get the problem. Do you want to overlay the two?

Comment: Yes. I want to overlay the two point clouds.

Comment: You could roughly overlay them by their centre of mass, but anything more sophisticated will probably involve more complex analysis and identification of features in the two sets of points which have to correspond.